# How to Sort a GridItemCollection

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a GridItemCollection defined as

```
GridItemCollection items = (GridItemCollection) Session["driveLayout"];
```

I want to sort the collection based off of one of the items in each GridItem.  In particularly this item

```
item["VolumeGroup"].ToString().ToLower()
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LINQ OrderBy extension method:

```
GridItemCollection items = (GridItemCollection)Session["driveLayout"];
var sortedItems = items.OfType<GridItem>().OrderBy(item => item.GridItems["VolumeGroup"].ToString().ToLower());
```

OfType() Converts an IEnumerable to an IEnumerable where T is the type specified in the type parameter. Since we know implicitly that GridItemCollection is a collection of items typed GridItem, we can do this.

Once we have an IEnumerable, we have access to all the LINQ extension methods, including OrderBy, which takes a lambda to use as the sort parameter.